# Swift Protocol as a Type

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am trying to use Swift Protocol as a Type. I have following code:

```
protocol STCMultipeerProtocol {
 typealias ErrorBlock = (NSError?)->();

 func start();
 func stop();
 func retryConnecting();
 func disconnect();
}

class STCConnectivityManager: NSObject {

 typealias VoidBlock = ()->();

 private var roleManager: STCMultipeerProtocol?
 private var completionBlock: VoidBlock?
 ....
}
```

Now, the problem is Compiler is giving me error:

```
Protocol 'STCMultipeerProtocol' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements.
```

I see that a lot of other people have seen this error but I am not able to understand the proper cause and solution for this issue.

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this issue

Comment: This probably has to do with `typealias ErrorBlock...` since it has a robust role in protocols.  If you drop it, the error should probably go away.

Comment: @BrianNickel - You are correct, the error is gone after taking out the type alias. Can you explain how did that effect it?

Comment: I'm skimming the docs right now for a good answer, but basically typealias in a protocol is not set in stone so the compiler doesn't have enough information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a `typealias` is used inside a protocol, it is referred to as a **Protocol Associated Type Declaration** and are associated with the "eventual type that conforms to the protocol" aka `Self`.  You'll see these a lot in the core Swift library for things like Sequences or basic types. The compiler needs that Self information to do its job and is therefore failing.

The good thing is that you don't need that typealias inside your protocol and can move it out as a global definition inside your namespace:

```
typealias ErrorBlock = (NSError?)->();

protocol STCMultipeerProtocol {

 func start();
 func stop();
 func retryConnecting();
 func disconnect();
}
```

If you have a lot of error types, you could call it a `MultipeerErrorBlock`.

Comment: What is the visibility of `ErrorBlock` then? Is it globally accessible in your entire application?

Comment: @AlexWayne yep, it is visible to the whole module.